# Do i need a seperate Memory Stick Pro to access a different Playstation Store on PSP

Tags: psn, psp

Black Rock Shooter is out however despite the fact that it's released on US and UK Playstation Network Stores it's not available in Australia, I messaged NISA and they repplied

> I regret to inform you that Black Rock Shooter: The Game is not available as
>   an Australian SKU. This is due to licensing restrictions coming from Japan.

this means i am now forced to get the game from another store, i know with the PSVita, the memory card you use gets locked to the store you open it with which in my case an Australian one

For a PSP however, i already have a memory card which i logged into my Australian PSN Account with which is my main card, i'm wondering if i need to use a separate card to access the UK Playstation Network Store cause with the PS3, you can't access 2 accounts on 1 profile, you have to create another profile in order to access another account (which is why i have 3, my main one, one for the UK STore and one for the US Store) and the PSP doesn't have the functionality to create different profiles on it

Comment: The answer to this question would mean falsifying information, specifically at least your address, to gain access to a PSN store outside your region. It is possible but I believe it vilates several terms of service with Sony and is out of bounds for questions you can pose on this site.

Comment: @TapanZee AFAIK creating multiple PSN accounts isn't against Sony's Terms of Use. The specifics may very depending on the region, but Sony had not made an official stance on having multiple accounts (especially ones from different regions).

Comment: @TapanZee it's common place for multiple accounts to be created as PS3 games are region free but the DLC will only work if brought from the same region store as the game (US Game = US DLC), people wouldn't need to do this if the store was a centralized server and DLC wasn't region locked, not to mention some games don't get released in all Regions as my question indicates, Black Rock Shooter is not available in Australia

Comment: @TapanZee My bad and many apologies. I was under the wrong impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether or not you have separate memory cards. It's the PSN account on the PSP that matters.

While you can install content from your PSN account on up to five PSPs, unlike with the PS3, any given PSP can **only be tied to a single PSN account at any given time**.

You can download all the content from both accounts, but you have to switch accounts to be able to access the software downloaded from each region. Only content on the account that is currently active will be available.

Comment: So does that mean if i want to download Black Rock Shooter i would have to have a separate PSP to connect to the UK Store as i already signed into my AUS PSN Account on my PSP Already, also, since the memory card doesn't matter, does that mean i can download UK DLC onto the same card as i downloaded Australian DLC

Comment: No it means you will have to log into your non-AUS account to play BRS, but back to your regular account to play your other games. What matters is the PSN account, not the memory cards. I'm not sure about DLC but it's probably locked to the region version of the original game.

Comment: if it's just logging in and out then that's all fine, i do that on the PS3 anyway between profiles, since according to the official website Black Rock Shooter doesn't advertise any multiplayer stuff i don't i'll need to log in to play it (unless what i download isn't the game but a client but i doubt that)